# What does Windows do with applications it removes?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I restarted Technic Launcher twice because I kept forgetting to turn on USB tethering, so there was no connection. On the third startup (Windows is connected now), it said something about the OS blocking that app, and that I may need to add an exception to the security settings (I don't remember it except, but I know this is somewhere along the lines). When I tried to start it up again to see the error message again, a message pops up saying

> The item 'TecnicLauncher.exe' that this shortcut refers to has been changed or moved, so this shortcut will no longer work properly.
>
> Would you like to delete this shortcut?

I've looked in the recycling bin and in windows security, I don't know if Windows deleted this or not.

I should mention that I moved technic launcher to `C:\Program Files` because for some reason I thought that it would show up in the start menu. However, Technic worked just fine until Windows removed it. The Technic folder is still there, but empty.

Comment: Newer versions of Windows contain a feature, when it encounters an untrusted file, a files trust is based on numerous factors.  One of those factors is based on the amount of users who have encountered the file itself.  An executable that is signed by the publisher will never have this problem  Likewise, I suspect the full message you encountered was, "This App has been blocked for your protection" which would confirm that this was indeed Windows attempting to block you from running what it believed (based on factors) was a malicious file.

Comment: (Continued)....It also appears that Windows Defender quarantined the executable.   Program Files of course is a protected directory.  So more restrictions are placed on that particular folder.  *I cannot think of what this feature is called otherwise I would submit an answer.*

Comment: It's called SmartScreen Filter;  Given that the exact message is unknown I won't be able to provide an answer.  It's also not clear what "it" was when you describe the message.

Answer (score 0):

This task is done by Windows defender. Windows Defender is a robust built-in antivirus tool that is distributed by Microsoft for free. Windows defender is much improved with latest security patches to make it very powerful. Whenever you see an app removed, that means it has been put in quarantine not actually removed, like Corona virus, isolated from the rest of the system. You an find those files at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Quarantine folder. It is hidden by default, so enable to show hidden folders in folder options. You can create exceptions in windows defender to allow apps in there.

Comment: The problem is that in Windows defender, under protection history, there is an entry from the 23 of may, and that's the only entry in both Windows Defender and the the folders in the quarantine folder. The Technic launcher is not there.

Answer (score 0):

First, undo everything you did, especially the moving of the folder to
`C:\Program Files` (unless you did that by re-installing the product and
not by moving).

Then go to
*Settings > Update & Security >Windows Security > Virus & threat protection*
and look in "Protection history" for the file `TecnicLauncher.exe`.
(It may perhaps be found in another link on this page.)

Once you find the file, click the down-arrow next to the name,
then click the "Actions" button and choose "Restore*.

To avoid this happening again in the future, back in "Virus & threat protection",
under "Virus & threat protection settings" click "Manage settings".
Scroll down, and under "Exclusions" click "Add or remove exclusions".
Click "Add an exclusion", then "Folder", and add the Technic Launcher folder.

Comment: Was the first thing I did, except for moving the folder from ```C:\Program Files```, as that folder was empty. There was nothing in protection history, so that didn't work out either. I did download the program again, and all the saved data was still there, so I'd really like to know what Windows did with it.

Comment: Windows has removed the file to a special quarantine folder, where it can no longer be accessed (and there's no point in forcing it). You need to exclude the program folder from being scanned by Windows Defender, and then the program can stay there safely. If you need to re-install, exclude the installation folder before installing, since otherwise Defender might remove the program again the moment that it appears in the folder.